# Use of gtkmm function g_timeout_add

Tags: c++, c++11, gtk

Could someone please show me an example of how to use the Gtkmm function [g_timeout_add](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add). I tried calling it like this: `g_timeout_add(100, &MainWindow::callbackFunc, processed);` but I get the error:

```
error: cannot convert ‘gboolean (MainWindow::*)(std::__cxx11::string) {aka int (MainWindow::*)(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>)}’ to ‘GSourceFunc {aka int (*)(void*)}’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘guint g_timeout_add(guint, GSourceFunc, gpointer)’
 g_timeout_add(100, &MainWindow::callbackFunc, processed);
```

And if I try to call it without the & (`g_timeout_add(100, MainWindow::callbackFunc, processed);`), then I get the following error:

```
error: invalid use of non-static member function
 g_timeout_add(100, MainWindow::callbackFunc, processed);
```

The callback function is defined as:

```
gboolean callbackFunc(std::string data);
```

Comment: `g_timeout_add` is a Glib function (so also a Gtk one) in C, not a C++ one from GtkMM

Comment: Then how could I register a callback function that is called every x milliseconds in GtkMM? Is this the correct way to register it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the [timeout](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-timeouts.html.en) section of the GtkMM tutorial documentation